# Unable to Launch PowerShell From Within VSCode (Access Denied)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, powershell-7.3

I have a weird issue that I can't seem to resolve. I recently installed PowerShell on Windows 10 and was hoping to integrate that within VS Code. When I try to launch the PowerShell terminal within VS Code I receive the error below:

The terminal process failed to launch: Access was denied to the path containing your executable "pathToPS\pwsh.exe". Manage and change your permissions to get this to work.

The weird thing is that I can launch PS without any issues using the same account/privileges as code. In addition, the error still appears when launching code as admin.

I'm not sure which permissions exactly are missing that VS code would need for it to run.

Comment: pwsh.exe is Powershell Core, not the built in version of Powershell (5.1)

Comment: You really need to write more about "I recently installed PowerShell on Windows 10", as there are too many possibilities that you installed it in a non-standard way.

Comment: @LexLi I installed it using winget. 

The specific command I used was: "winget install Microsoft.PowerShell"

Comment: @Scepticalist that is correct. The built in windows powershell does function as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1626#issuecomment-1352801406 Sounds like winget is a risky way of installing PowerShell right now, and you might reconsider the classic MSI way.

Comment: @LexLi Tried reinstalling using the .msi package, and I'm getting the same results. I even tried installing an older version (7.1.0.0) and no dice.

Comment: Can you try to use Process Monitor to dig further into the error? 1) Confirm that access denied to that file path can be observed, 2) Confirm the user account that is denied access.